# Issue with image auto resize on firefox

Tags: wordpress, css, firefox

I have an issue with the CSS of my website, but only under Firefox.
Basically the theme should resize correctly images and text to fit the width of the column.

On Safari and Chrome the following code is working correctly :

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0px none;
}
```

But on firefox images (and I've just seen also text above) is displayed uncorrectly.

Example: http://www.ange-studio.com/paint-in-estelle/
Just need to try with Safari/Chrome on one side and Firefox on the other.

Any idea of the CSS to fix?

Comment: Could you give us your HTML code?. If you use max-width: 100%, it means that the maximum width is going to reach is 100% (it doesn't assure you is going to stretch to 100%, it depends on the browser). You could try to change it to width: 100% or add width: auto;

Comment: You can see the output HTML just using the source of the link provided. Goal is to reach 100% of the column and it's working well on Safari and Chrome :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot access your site from here (proxy firewall), anyway I think that if you want it to work you will have to add at least the next styles: Example -> max-width: 900px; max-height: 900px; height: auto; width: auto;. Note that max-width and max-height are in number of pixels.

Comment: Ok, it helped a lot: I must not set max-width and max-height since it will force resize to that dimension and we do not want that. But, adding  `width: 100%;` to existing parameters seems to fix it on firefox without breaking other browsers. Note that real width and height are already set inline in img tag, per element.

Comment: change `max-width` to `width`.